# To understand spaces

Tags: bash, zsh

This is a one-line bash script by Ishmael Smyrnow to clear macOS icon cache:

```bash
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store; sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \; ; sleep 3;sudo touch /Applications/* ; killall Dock; killall Finder
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/ismyrnow/e92c6010cda9325b2d8811387a05f224)

I try to understand how to change it back to its multiple-line version. Here is what I have now:

```bash
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm -rfv {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rfv {} \;
sleep 3
sudo touch /Applications/*
killall Dock
killall Finder
```

I do understand in Ishmael's version semicolons are used for newlines and `\;` for literal semicolons. But what is the purpose to have a space between the two semicolons and after the asterisk? Is it safe to remove them?

```bash
 -exec rm -rfv {} \; ;
```

```bash
/Applications/* ;
```

Comment: most likely it's just for visual separation. `\;;` might look like it's a single thingy, when it's not. Not that readability seems to have been a main concern when they've crammed a seven command 250-character scriptlet onto one line...

Comment: The `\;` at the end of find(1) is there [on purpose](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). The backslash is there so the shell doesn't interpret (and thus remove) the semicolon `;`. The semicolon is part of the syntax of the `-exec` argument to find(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When to and not to use spaces in shell language syntax is not trivial.

It's also important to note there different kinds of spaces:

- space and tab are used to separate tokens in the syntax
- newline separates tokens but also separates commands. For instance:

  ```
  array=(
    foo bar
    baz
  )
  ```

  (a syntax from zsh now supported by several other shells) or ksh's (from C):

  ```
  (( 1
  + 2
  ))
  ```

  Or POSIX sh (but also from ksh):

  ```
  var=$((
    a + 
    b
  ))
  ```

  above space, tab or newline can separate the elements.

  But:

  ```
  cmd a
  cmd b
  ```

  runs two separate commands.

  Where newline can be used in place of space is not always clear and can vary between shells.
- in some shells (including bash) some other characters classified as *blank* in the locale can be used as token delimiters in the syntax and that can include characters such as U+00A0 the non-breaking space (only in locales where it's classified as *blank* and encoded on one byte in the case of `bash`).

Then there are quoting operators (`"..."`, `'...'`, `$'...'`, `$"..."`, `\`) which can be used to remove whatever special meaning a character otherwise has in the shell syntax.

And there are a number of special characters (mainly `();<>&|` and to some extent `` `$ ``) which either alone or possibly combined with others form tokens in the syntax that can also delimit words and so don't need spaces around them.

For instance, in ksh, you can write:

```
[[(a == b||d>c)&&0<1 ]]&&(echo yes)|cat
```

Instead of:

```
[[ ( a == b || d > c ) && 0 < 1 ]] && ( echo yes ) | cat
```

As `||`, `(`, `&&`, `<`, `&&`... are individual tokens that can delimit.

In bash (5.1 at least), you'll find that  you need:

```
[[(a == b||d>c)&&0 <1 ]]&&(echo yes)|cat
```

Or otherwise you seem to be hitting a sort of bug:

```
$ bash -c '[[(a == b||d>c)&&0<1 ]]&&(echo yes)|cat'
bash: -c: line 1: unexpected token 284 in conditional command
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near `&0<'
bash: -c: line 1: `[[(a == b||d>c)&&0<1 ]]&&(echo yes)|cat'
```

(possibly because outside of `[[...]]`, in `cmd 0<file`, `0<` in itself is an operator so likely treated as a separate token).

In:

```
foo \;;bar
```

There's no ambiguity, that's a `foo` word, space treated as separator, a quoted `;` (`\;` being the same as `';'` or `";"` here) and the `;` token and then `bar`. So it is treated the same as:

```
foo ';' ; bar
```

Adding spaces doesn't harm and helps with legibility.

That code could also be written (and improved to):

```
sudo zsh -c '
  rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
  find /private/var/folders/ \
    "("
       -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -o \
       -name com.apple.iconservices \
    ")" -prune -exec rm -rfv {} +
  sleep 3
  touch /Applications/*'
killall Dock
killall Finder
```

Where you'll notice:

- `sudo` is run only once with a multiline quoted string passed as an argument to a separate zsh invocation inside which all the characters lose their special meaning to the outer shell.
- `\` followed by newline is another special case not mentioned above. That makes the newline disappear (for the inner shell; for the outer shell the backslash and newline are inside single quotes so remain literal).
- we call only one `find`
- we use `+` instead of `;` to delimit (for `find`, not for the shell) the list of arguments that to make up the command that `-exec` executes, so `rm` is called once with all the directories to remove instead of once for each.
- we use `-prune` so `find` doesn't attempt to descend into the directories that `rm` is going to remove anyway.
- I use `"("` instead of `\(` as I find it more legible. Usually I would use `'('` be here the whole thing is inside `'...'` so we can't use that.
- we use `zsh -c` instead of `sh -c` because `sh` has that misfeature whereby when globs don't match they are passed literally, so in `sh`, `touch /Applications/*` would create a file called `*` in `/Applications` if there was no non-hidden file there. In zsh, if there's no match, you get an error instead.